# why eclipse does not move all jar files to server lib folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I have mvn web application project. I run

```
mvn clean install
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

in    ***target{project-name}\WEB-INF\lib*** dictonary, here is all jar files (amount of all jar is 77), that I have  declared in pom.xml.

1. I have created new server in eclipse .
2. add priject to server.

when I open servers project lib dictonary  **path\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\webapps{project-name}\WEB-INF\lib**
I found all jar files, except one (amount of all jar is 76).

why this happens?

I do not have this jar file:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.lazyluke</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4jdbc-remix</artifactId>
      <version>0.2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

The same happens , for example, when I add another jars in pom.xml. I do not understand why eclipse does not copy all the jars...

Eclipse version: Luna
Tomcat version: 8.0.14

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with eclipse-maven synchronization. If pom is changed this doesn't get synchronized with webapps already deployed on the Tomcat. So you need to do

```
Tomcat>Clean...
```

This will do the sync. Also make sure maven dependencies are added in

```
Project>Properties>Deployment Assesmbly
```